# how this code adds a comma after city name automatically?

Tags: jquery

```
var arr = [];
$('#inputs input').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        arr.push(this.value);
    }
    else {
        arr.splice(arr.indexOf(this.value), 1);
    }
    $('#target').val(arr + '');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
```

how comma is appearing automatically in textbox ?? and in code its not intented to print

Comment: I think it is the implicit toString method of the Array object, called when `arr` is implicitly converted with the emtpy string on last line

Comment: Please post your relevant HTML markup.

Comment: When you appending string to Array object in javascript it converts that Array Object to comma separated string value.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is the implicit toString method of the Array object, called when `arr` is  concatenated (so implicitly converted) with the emtpy string on last line

For exemple

```
console.log([1,2,3].toString()) // This will return "1,2,3"
console.log([1,2,3]+'') // This will return "1,2,3" too !
```